# Linear transformation in Lebesgue measure (not integration!): Change of variable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, linear-transformations, change-of-variable

Here's a problem that I'm stuck with for a while.

If $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is Lebesgue measurable, and $T:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is a linear transformation, then:

$(i)$ Show that $T(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable

$(ii)$ Show that $m(T(E))=~|\mbox{det}(T)| \times m(E)$

$(iii)$ Give a counter example that if $T:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^{d'}$ is a linear map to a space $\mathbb{R}^d$ of strictly smaller dimension than $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $T(E)$ need not be Lebesgue measurable.

I think that the problem can be solved without involving the *Lebesgue integration* as the book I'm following introduced *Lebesgue integration* after the section on *Lebesgue measure* (and hence, this exercise). So to avoid any kind of circularity, I'm looking for a solution without relying on *Lebesgue integration*. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hints: for parts (i) and (ii) consider the the cases of $\det(T) = 0$ and $\det(T) \not=0$ separately. When $\det(T) \not= 0$, what does $T$ do to open balls and their volumes? open sets? Now use approximation properties of Lebesgue measure by open sets. For part (iii) consider the projection of $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ by selecting the first coordinate, and then choose $E$ to be an appropriate subset of measure zero (remember, any set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ cartesian product with a set $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ of measure zero is a set $A \times B$ of measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @J.Loreaux perhaps considering the volume of hyper rectangles instead of balls is more intuitive here :)

Comment: @J.Loreaux: Thanks! It was helpful.